# First module, how to create a simple control panel form?

Tags: module

I have successfully built the front end of my first module. Its a simple module that does currency conversions.

I need to create a simple control panel page for my module that allows me to add a decimal number into three different fields which is saved in the database (already have the database created on install of module).

I am a complete newbie, so wondering if anyone can give me an idea of how to create a basic form that submits to the database as I have been unable to find anywhere that shows an easy to understand version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [Module Development Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi Yuri. Thanks. I already read through this dozens of times, but cant figure out how to get the control panel part. I have managed the front end, but the control panel seems much more complicated.

I am looking for a stripped down simple form which I could then learn from.

Comment: Did you download and study the example code referenced on that page?
Also, check this [screencast](http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/how-to-develop-expressionengine-add-on/) by Low

Comment: Hi Yuri. Yes, I have managed to get a little further thank you. I will post a new question.